# Sharing With Twitter and Facebook Using External Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I would like to share some text and an image from my web application to a user of my web application's facebook and twitter pages.  What is the best approach to do this?  So I need to have my user authenticate facebook and twitter and then user the twitter and facebook apis to update?  I wasn't sure if they was an easier way...I would prefere a java server or javascript solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ seems to be the right fit for facebook.